# cURL HTTP transfer data

Tags: curl, data-transfer

I am trying to use cURL for the first time to download some data.
I am working with the cmd prompt in Windows 7.
I have a txt file with lots of URLs where the files I want to download shoul be.
In the website I am using to retrieve the data I want, the help says to use this function to download the dataset:

```
for i in `cat <url text file>`; do curl $i -OL -s; done
```

but after some tries I culdn't come up with a solution so far.
What am I supposed to insert instead of that ""? I thought simply to point to the directory where the txt file is stored and specify its name and extension, like this:

```
C:\Users\Umberto>for i in `cat C:\Users\Umberto\Downloads\data_url_script_2013-03-01_062649.txt`; do curl $i -OL -s; done
```

I receive the message

```
i non atteso
```

(which means "i not expected")
Do You have any clue how to solve this?
Many thanks in advance.

One up to date note:
I succeded in downloading the file in the current directory, but only specifying one URL instead of the list I had. What I am interested to do now is download all the data I have (specified in a list of URLs within the text file) by one single command (as the one specified above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to run some sort of Unix style shell command in the windows 7 command prompt.

You should be able to achieve the same result if you run a similar command in a Windows Powershell command prompt.
If you unzip the curl tool to the following folder: C:\Users\Umberto\Curl the following should work if you run it in a Windows Powershell command prompt.

```
 Get-Content C:\Users\Umberto\Downloads\data_url_script_2013-03-01_062649.txt | %{C:\Users\Umberto\Curl\curl.exe $_ -OL -s}
```

Comment: It worked, thank You so much! What's the difference between windows cmd propmt and the Powershell? Is the second one suitable to run Unix style commands while the first one doesn't? Sorry for the question, as it's another issue, I will document on this. Thank You so much again!

Comment: Powershell is a more powerfull command line shell than the older windows cmd prompt. Your task could probably also have been solved in windows cmd prompt too, just with different commands than the Unix shell you tried first and different from the Powershell commands I posted.