# How to run a cURL command for downloading data from a text file in Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, curl

I am working with the cmd prompt in Windows 7 (Win32). I have a txt file with a list of URLs of the files I would like to download. Similar to [cURL HTTP transfer data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156983/curl-http-transfer-data), I am using the following command:

```
C:\...\Desktop>for i in `cat curltest.txt`; do curl $i -OL -s; done
```

and I get the following error:
i was unexpected at this time

I have been able to successfully run an even simpler command (i.e., curl http://gooogle.com).

I read at [cURL HTTP transfer data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156983/curl-http-transfer-data) that
"It looks like you are attempting to run some sort of Unix style shell command in the windows 7 command prompt."
And, rather than running it in a Windows Powershell command prompt, I would like to run it in the Windows command prompt.

Does anyone know how I might modify this command so that it will run using Windows cmd.exe?

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: have you looked at this? http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I'm not too familiar with curl, so I don't know what the extra flags (-OL -s) do, but you can run powershell commands from cmd.exe, e.g. `powershell -command "cat .\urls.txt | % { curl $_ }"` (of course, they are run by a powershell process, but I don't think that would matter since you won't notice it :))

Answer (score 3):

```
for /f "delims=" %u in (curltest.txt) do curl -OLs "%u"
```

In windows, `for` command sintax is different. This is the equivalent in windows of the code in your question.

If it will be included in a batch file, it will be necessary to double the percent signs

```
for /f "delims=" %%u in (curltest.txt) do curl -OLs "%%u"
```